# React Native Android: How to install Closed Alpha testing build instead of Production?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-play, google-play-console

I have a production build of my React Native app on the Google Play Store, and have created a new version that I'm releasing to a Closed Alpha track for testing. When I go to that Closed Alpha track, it has a link that users should follow in order to install the build.

[image]

In a previous app, I didn't have a Production build and instead had only the Closed Alpha track, and following this link successfully installed the test build. However, with the current app, when I follow this link, it installs the Production build instead of the Closed Alpha one. Does anyone know how I can get the link to install the Closed Alpha test build instead of the Production one?

Answer (score 0):

For installing the closed testing track you must join as a beta tester. You should add your email id to the tester list in the closed alpha testing track. In play store, you should look for 'Join Beta Program' and join it. Uninstall the app if already installed, or just refresh the page, it should show you the alpha track. Make sure you are logged in to play store with the same email id you have added in tester list.